# How to show and hide a div based on the input in a textbox using only basic javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is based on an assigment to create a search engine that can pull up a search box when an input is detected. We aren't allowed to use jquery or ajax... Only basic javascript. I'm quite new to programming myself so please bare with my lack of skills... So far is my basis of my code. 
I created an input text box in html 
`<input id="text" type="text">`

Then I created a div containing an  ul which contains an li (eventually I hope to make this more dynamic).

Here is my attempt at using JS to create a function that would cause the keyword search to appear when the value of text is greater than 0...

```js
function searchBox() {
  var x = document.getElementById('text').value;
  var y = document.getElementById('keyword_searcher');
  if (x.length > 0) {
    y.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    y.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
#keyword_searcher {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 400;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 30px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="text" type="text">
</div>

<div id="keyword_searcher" onload="searchBox();">
  <ul id="results">
    <li>Song 1</li>
    <li>Song 2</li>
    <li>Song 3</li>
    <li>Song 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I would be very grateful for any help I can get. Thank you !!

Comment: By the way. It is really poor practice to instantiate the variables x and y inside of the function like that because they refer to static (always there) dom elements. Try bringing them outside of the function. That will reduce the amount of memory usage and garbage collection necessary.

Comment: I take it back for the x variable. But you can still get a reference to the element instead of searching for it every time.

Comment: okies I will try that, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an event handler on the text input using unobtrusive way. The event `onload` is only for `<body>` tag.

```js
function searchBox() {
  var x = document.getElementById('text').value;
  var y = document.getElementById('keyword_searcher');
  if (x.length > 0) {
    y.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    y.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

document.getElementById("text").addEventListener("onkeyup", function () {
  searchBox();
});
```

```css
#keyword_searcher {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 400;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 30px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="text" type="text" onkeyup="searchBox();" />
</div>

<div id="keyword_searcher">
  <ul id="results">
    <li>Song 1</li>
    <li>Song 2</li>
    <li>Song 3</li>
    <li>Song 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: it didn't work unfortunately :(. Thank you for your help! :D

Comment: @naturesenshi Updated. Check?

Comment: yep that works. Now I have the same problem with my onscreen keyboard I had implemented on my full code...

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, the function doesn't know when it should be fired. To tell the function to fire when someone starts typing, do this:

Edit this line:

```
<input id="text" type="text">
```

To look like this:

```
<input id="text" type="text" onkeyup ="searchBox()">
```

This should fire the function when someone enters something into the input field.

Comment: I tried it on my full html script and I have a separate onscreen keyboard that is linked to the value of the text box. When the value of the text box changes using the onscreen keyboard nothing happens. However onkeydown from my direct keyboard i does work. Thank you so much for your help btw :)

Comment: Another function would be the `onchnage` method. Unfortunately, It only fires when you remove the focus from the input, or press enter. However, if you have an on screen keyboard, you may be able to tap into it and make it call the method for each letter. Or, you can set the `onmouseup` method, or set the `document.body.onTouchEnd` for mobile.